# Using .each(), how to wait for animation end?

Tags: jquery, animation

In a web application, I'm using `.each()` to iterate a set of items.

In the body of the function, I'm looking for a specific item that I want to show or hide using animation.

This is working well. However, I would like to fire a function when all animations have ended, only once.

How can I do this?

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/WCESQ/1/) that illustrates the problem.

Basically, I have something like this:

```
<button id="x">Show</button>
<ol>
    <li><span style="display:none">One</span>

    </li>
    <li><span style="display:none">Two</span>

    </li>
    <li><span style="display:none">Three</span>

    </li>
    <li><span style="display:none">Four</span>

    </li>
</ol>
<pre id="log">
</pre>
```

and js:

```
$(function () {

    $("#x").click(function () {
        $("li").each(function () {
            $(this).find("span").show({
                complete: function () {
                    $("#log").append("completed\n");
                }
            }).promise().done(function () {
                $("#log").append("done\n");
            });
        });    
    });
});
```

In this case, both "completed" and "done" are pushed to the log element.

I would like to call the "done" function only once, when all animations have ended.

How can I do that?

PS: I know my snippet could written as: `$("li > span").show(...)`, but the `each` construct represents my real code.

**[edit] The .each keyword must be kept, as my actual code is built with each. My snippets are simpler just to represent the problem**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to the animated collection (the spans).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/WCESQ/2/)

```
$("li").each(function () {
    $(this).find("span").show({
        complete: function () {
            $("#log").append("completed\n");
        }
    })}).find("span").promise().done(function () {
        $("#log").append("done\n");
    });
```

---

## .promise()

> **.promise( [type ] [, target ] )**
>
> **Returns:** Promise
>
> **Description:** Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a certain type **bound to the collection**, queued or not, have
> finished.

Comment: I **have** to use the `.each` function to reflect my real and far more complex code.

Comment: @SteveB I've changed it back to the each

Comment: thanks you. I'm surprised I can call `.promise()` on the result of the `.each()`

Comment: @SteveB Don't get confused, it has nothing to do with the `each` function. It's just a simple jQuery chaining. The point is that you have to make `promise` work on the relevant collection of animated elements

Answer (score 3):

store the deferreds in an array, and use that to see when all animations are finished :

```
$(function () {
    $("#x").click(function () {
        var arr = [];
        $("li").each(function() {
            var def = $(this).find("span").show('slow', function () {
                $("#log").append("completed\n");
            });
            arr.push(def)
        });
        $.when.apply($, arr).then(function () {
            $("#log").append("done\n");
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WCESQ/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple version

```
$("li span").show({
    complete: function () {
        $("#log").append("completed\n");
    }
}).promise().done(function () {
    $("#log").append("done\n");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MKCmM/)

Comment: As I said, I use the each function. My actual code cannot be refactored to this simple selector. The jsfiddle reflect this